# Raptr Cookie Clicker hours?

Tags: cookie-clicker, raptr

[Raptr is tracking playtime for Cookie Clicker](http://raptr.com/game/Cookie-Clicker?platform=Web). How does that work? Is it only tracking manually tracked gametime or does the desktop app automagically detect that it is running?

I see people who have spurts of 9+ hours on cookie clicker, but manual tracking caps at 6 hours at a time so I suspect some form of sorcery. If there is some automagic, what are the conditions and limitations for tracking the gametime? Is it just certain browsers? Does it have to be the active tab? Does the browser have to have focus? Can the browser be minimized as long as the cookie clicker tab is active?

I've been playing, only refreshing for updates for about 24 days and give or take a shutdown or 4, that probably still amounts to about 23 days of total playtime. I had Raptr running, I thought, but I guess it was signed out or needed an update or something because it didn't track any of the playtime. Maybe I needed to add the game to my library before it would automagically check. Cookie clicker itself tracks start date, not hours, so I don't expect an accurate tally of the actual hours to date, but I would like to track from now on without having to check in every 6 hours to manually track.

**How exactly does hour tracking for Cookie Clicker on Raptr work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have Cookie Clicker as your active tab to let Raptr track your gametime and the browser doesn't need to have focus. If you're browsing with multiple tabs, everytime you switch out from Cookie Clicker, Raptr will notify you something like 'Cookie Clicker - 9 seconds played'.

This behavior has been tested with Chrome and Firefox. With Explorer I'm under the impression that gametime isn't tracked at all.